# live-chat application message and user model

Tags: php, laravel, chat

I'm developing a live chat application and i don't know which is the proper db structure. I thought that the best solution is to have a Message model that belongs to a Sender and to a Receiver. In this way things should work, but when i seed i have a lot of problems, like only the first user got the relations accessible. I share my code below.

Message Migration

```php
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->text('content');
            $table->foreignUuid('from_id')->references('uuid')->on('users');
            $table->foreignUuid('to_id')->references('uuid')->on('users');
        });
    }
```

User migration

```php
            $table->id();
            $table->uuid('uuid')->unique();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('profile')->default(public_path('images/default_profile.jpg'));
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
```

Message Model

```php
class Message extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = "messages";

    public function sender()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'from_id');
    }
    public function receiver()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'to_id');
    }
}
```

User model

```php
    public function sent()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Message::class, 'from_id');
    }
    public function received()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Message::class, 'to_id');
    }
    public function contacts()
    {
```

DatabaseSeeder

```php
 User::factory()->create([
            'name' => 'username',
            'email' => 'admin@admin.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('password')
        ]);
        Message::factory()
            ->count(200)
            ->create();
        User::factory()->count(10)->create();
        $users = User::all();
        $messages = Message::all();
        User::all()->each(function ($user) use ($users) {
            do {
                $idsToAttach = $users->random(rand(1, 3))->pluck('id')->toArray();
                $idsToAttach = array_diff($idsToAttach, array($user->id));
            } while (count($idsToAttach) <= 0);
            $user->contacts()->attach(
                $idsToAttach
            );
        });
        $messages->each(function ($message) use ($users) {
            do {
                $sender = $users->random(1)->pluck('uuid');
                $receiver = $users->random(1)->pluck('uuid');

            } while ($sender[0] == $receiver[0]);
            $message->receiver()->associate(
                $receiver[0]
            );
            $message->sender()->associate(
                $sender[0]
            );
            $message->save();
        });
    }
```

Comment: There are a few chat packages available for Laravel. You might want to consider using one of them rather than recreating the wheel (unless you have a specific reason not to in which case rock on!) or reviewing their code base to see how they have implemented things as a point of reference.

Comment: Nope, i can't use extern packages. Really i think that my logic should work, but i think my problem is on seeders.

Answer (score 0):

your seeder can be way easier,
maybe in your user factory, you can override `configure()` method as below, and register an `afterCreating` callback as below:

```
public function configure(): UserFactory
{
    return $this->afterCreating(Closure::fromCallable([$this, 'attachRelations']));
}
```

where `attachRelations` is a method that will be called after every user creation, you can do many things in there, things like :

```
function attachRelations(User $user)
    {
        // Assign a random amount of languages to a user
        $languages = Language::all();
        $user->languages()->sync($languages->random(rand(1, $languages->count())));

        // Assign a fake avatar to a user, just a record no file
        $avatar = Avatar::factory()->make();
        $user->avatar()->save($avatar);
    }
```

this way, I will attach a random amount of languages to each user, and also assign an avatar record, I hope you got the idea
laravel doc: [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database-testing#factory-callbacks)
let me know if you need help